# If $f$ is differentiable from $[0,1]$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(\dfrac{i}{n})=\int_{0}^{1}fdx$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Could anyone help find a starting point for tackling this problem? As it stands I don't really know where to begin.

Comment: this is the definition of the integral.

Comment: Are you sure that $f$ must be differentiable?

Comment: How do you define the integral? It is often defined this way, and the other way is to define using fundamental theorem of calculus. You must tell us your definition.

Comment: Riemann integrable instead of differentiable should suffice

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen I think it does not work for Thomae's function.

Comment: OK. If f is differentiable it is continuous, therefore integrable. Is it true?

Answer (score 2):

$f$ can be just assume that it is Riemann integrable (which is less than continuous, which is less than differentiable).

Then, you will have your result for the partition $0=x_0<x_1=\frac{1}{n}<\ldots<x_i=\frac{i}{n}<\ldots<x_{n}=1,$ by taking the ${\bf right}$ Riemann sum.

$\Delta_x=\frac{1}{n},$ $\alpha=0$ and $\beta=1,$ hence, from the formula

$\lim_n \sum_{i=1}^n f(a+i\frac{\beta-\alpha}{n})\Delta_x=\int_0^1 f(x)dx,$ you have your result.